# Drawing from .dxf-import to QGIS is situated off the CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, dxf, autocad

I created a drawing (extent of an area) in Autocad LT 2021 which I want to import to QGIS. In QGIS are the boundaries of a city which should be overlayed with my drawing. My drawing is already geopositioned in AutoCAD in the CRS ETRS89.UTM33. I have set everything in the right CRS but the drawing appears beyond the extent of the worldmap. I can't just not find the mistake. Can somebody tell me what went wrong?

Comment: Are the drawing units in Autocad the same as in your project settings in QGIS?

Comment: Did you position the drawing correctly when you created it, or did you simply start drawing next to the origin? Can you provide exemplary coordinates and tell us, which CRS they should be in? Have you "mixed" EPSG25833 and EPSG5650 (both UTM33N, but the second has the UTM-zone as leading numbers)?